# How to translate «State of the art»?

Tags: перевод

«State of the art» is a chapter of almost every western dissertation and also is mentioned in most English language scientific papers. But how would one translate this phrase into Russian?

Online translation tools get lost and attempt verbatum translations, which completely miss the point (and begin talking about art).

A dissertation for MRes can take a following form:

1. Introduction
2. Literature review / State of the art (depending on what you are describing more)
3. Problem / Aims and objectives (depending on your wording, etc)
4. Work done
5. Findings
6. Conclusion

Something like 'Future research' can be a part of conclusion or be a section before it.

I am using a submitted and accepted dissertation of mine as a reference for this.

Comment: You mean "state of the art", not "state of art".

Comment: In Russian dissertations "актуальность, цели и задачи исследования" is written in the first chapter "Введение".

Comment: Are there any other common parts in Western dissertations? What are their names? Is "State of the art" the first part of a dissertation?

Comment: The premise of this question, that nearly all dissertations have a section called "state of the art", is false. I have never seen such a term used in mathematics. A related term that is used is "background", which is translated as бэкграунд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Russian it’s called *состояние вопроса*.

Comment: Googling also gives "современное состояние вопроса", "состояние изученности вопроса", "Современное состояние и ближайшие задачи изучения тюркских языков", "анализ состояния проблемы и постановка задачи исследования", etc.

Comment: "Современное" is very important here

Comment: Never written a thesis in Russian, but I would say `обзор литературы`.

Comment: @OlegLobachev, это было бы прямым переводом для упомянутого в вопросе «Literature review».  Я думаю, что т. v010dya не испытывал затруднений в переводе _этого_ словосочетания.

Comment: Ну вопрос в том, как звучит устоявшееся название раздела научной работы. Как всегда, возможны варианты, но "обзор..." не вызывает у меня отторжения в этом качестве.

Comment: @OlegLobachev, да?  А мне показалось, что вопрос был в том, как перевести...

Comment: @OlegLobachev, сиречь «состояние вопроса» у вас вызывает отторжение?

Comment: Вопрос был "как перевести в диссертации". Что до "состояния вопроса" — категорического отторжения оно у меня не вызывает, но лично я бы так не написал.

Comment: @OlegLobachev, мы, кажется, пошли по кругу.

Comment: Переформулирую. Я не отрицаю возможности такого перевода, но он мне не нравится.

Answer (score 2):

The Collins Dictionary says:

> the level of knowledge and development achieved in a technique,
>   science, etc, esp at present

So I'd use something from the list below:

- по последнему слову (техники)
- последние (новейшие) достижения (медицины)
- новейшие течения (в литературе)
- последний писк (моды)
- передовые (результаты ч-л)
- на гребне волны

Comment: Не вижу среди ваших вариантов достойного кандидата на название раздела в кандидатской/докторской диссертации.

Comment: @Artemix "Обзор новейших литературных течений/течений в литературе" вам не подходит? Добавлю еще один вариант.

Comment: Ну, если добавить "обзор", то хорошо. Но этот вариант никак не выделен и теряется среди "писков моды" и "последних слов техники". Мне кажется что спрашивающего больше интересовал вариант подходящий для заголовка в диссертации чем все возможные варианты перевода.

Comment: Я дал развернутый вариант, подходящий не только для диссертации, но и для множества других случаев. Если для кого-то сложно трансформировать фразу "новейшие течения в литературе" в "Обзор новейших литературных течений", то сомневаюсь, что есть смысл начинать диссер. Верю, что ТС успешно с этим справился :)

Comment: дело в том, что в диссертации по медицине, например, раздел "новейшие течения в литературе" хоть с обзором, хоть без, неуместен.

Answer (score 1):

в технике, в патентоведении, [the] state of the art = уровень техники. следует различать, т. к. state-of-the-art (с дефисами) = современный.

в написании технических/научных курсовых/диссертаций, Literature review / State of the art правильнее переводить как "Патентно-информационный поиск".